# Navigation ideas

Tags: ros, navigation, lidar, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to navigation and currently I have a wheeled robot and I want to implement various navigation algorithms with it. For now though, I don't have an odometer for localization and I currently use only a lidar. I have managed to do some obstacle avoidance with it, but I am out of ideas for now.

If you could help me with some navigation algorithms that don't require an odometer for localization, I would be more than happy to hear them.

Thank you for your answers and for your time in advance,

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241298/navigation-ideas/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ssj](https://answers.ros.org/users/31577/ssj/) on 2017-08-14**:
hello
i am new to ros and trying to use navigation stack for obstacle avoidance. how did you manage obstacle avoidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm not sure if it is what you want but you can use the SLAM for localization.
You can use `hector_mapping` (`hector_slam`), I know it is possible to use it without odometry.
There is also another algorithm for SLAM: `slam_gmappping` (`gmapping`) but I don't know if it is possible to use it without odometry.
You can find all the information about those 2 methods on the ros wiki (by typing hector_slam and gmapping).

I hope it will help you,
lfr

---

Originally posted by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) with karma: 201 on 2016-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0